# Sub Query Where X in (from...?

Tags: linq

How can i do this ?
where tsc.TransactionID in (from t in Transactions where ........

```
        Eg:
        var query = (from tsd in TransactionSampleDetails 
        join tsc in TransactionSamples on  tsd.TransactionSampleID equals tsc.TransactionSampleID
        join qp in QualityParameters on tsd.ParameterID equals qp.ParameterID
        where tsc.TransactionID in (from t in Transactions where t.StockpileID == 7122 select t.TransactionID)
        select new 
        { 
            TransactionID = tsc.TransactionID,
            ParameterName = qp.Parameter,
            ParameterValue = tsd.ActualValue
        });
```

Comment: Ok got this as 
var query = (from tsd in TransactionSampleDetails 
   join tsc in TransactionSamples on  tsd.TransactionSampleID equals tsc.TransactionSampleID
   join qp in QualityParameters on tsd.ParameterID equals qp.ParameterID
   where (from t in Transactions where t.StockpileID == 7122 select t.TransactionID).Contains(tsc.TransactionID)
   select new 
   { 
    TransactionID = tsc.TransactionID,
    ParameterName = qp.Parameter,
    ParameterValue = tsd.ActualValue
   });
query.Dump();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Contains:

```
where (from t in Transactions 
       where t.StockpileID == 7122 
       select t.TransactionID).Contains(tsc.TransactionID)
```

Mind you, it might be more efficient and appropriate to use another join:

```
join t in Transactions.Where(t => t.StockpileID == 7122)
  on tsc.TransactionId equals t.TransactionID
```